# Como abrir nova aba sem bloquear pop-up após windows.open()?

Tags: javascript, popup

estou com dificuldades a abrir nova aba depois de um `confirm` e `windows.open`, segue o código:

```
    function dec(){
      var matricula =  "<?php echo $matricula;?>";  
      var receita =  "<?php echo $receita;?>";                           
    decisao = confirm("Matricula: "+matricula+"\nReceita: "+receita+"\nReceita cadastrada com sucesso!"+"\n\n"+"Deseja imprimi-la?");
    if (decisao)
window.open('imprimir_receitas.php?matricula='+matricula+'&receita='+receita, 'blank');
    }
```

Após clicar em ok o pop-up é bloqueado, ah alguma forma de abrir esta aba sem ser bloqueada?

Comment: Já tentou definir os parametros de altura e largura? Qual o browser?

Comment: @Vanderson jpa tentei sim com tamanho, por exemplo passando junto aos parametros os valores 'width=200, height=100'. mas nada adiantou :/

Comment: Em todos os browsers isso?

Comment: @Vanderson sim, nos principais firefox e chrome acontece isso. IE funciona mas não é totalmente compatível com meu sistema.

Comment: Esses dois exemplos estão funcionando. Testa ai: - http://jsbin.com/aboluk/2/edit?html,js,output - http://output.jsbin.com/aboluk/148/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Pessoal, acabei solucionando este problema utilizando modal.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz de uma forma utilizando o attr, devido o bloqueio do window.open veja:

```
$(document).on('click', '#sus-div-que-abraca-o-item > div', function() {
    var campoRadio  = $(this).find("input[type='radio']").val();
    var quantidade = 1;
    $("#link-bto").attr({
        href: "../comprar.php?categoria="+categoria+"&quantidade="+quantidade,
        target: "_blank",
   });
});
```